# morris-bar-chart different usage

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, morris.js, jscharts

I'm working on a game and I have different prizes like **per day**, **per week** and **per month** and I want to show top 5 users per prize.

What I wonder about is a way to show all of them in the same bar chart for each prize.

As conclusion, I need 3 parts as `xkeys` named **monthly**, **weekly**, **daily** and each part covering 5 columns as `yKeys` for top 5 players.

Since we have this as morris default example, is that possible?

```
 Morris.Bar({
    element: 'morris-bar-chart',
    data: [{y: '2006',a: 100,b: 90},
           {y: '2007',a: 75,b: 65},
           {y: '2008',a: 50,b: 40},
           {y: '2009',a: 75,b: 65},
           {y: '2010',a: 50,b: 40},
           {y: '2011',a: 75,b: 65},
           {y: '2012',a: 100,b: 90}],
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
    labels: ['Series A', 'Series B'],
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true
});
```

I am looking for something like this image:

[image]

if there is any other ways to reach what i'm looking for with different charts or something else i'm all ears
i appreciate your helps

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Why don't you make 3 different charts? One for `Monthly`, one for `Weekly` and one for `Daily`.

Comment: Yes that is an option but it will be so crowdy 3charts for each one.  I wish I could have something like that picture... @krlzlx